# Action Event error

Tags: java, swing, exception, actionlistener

Why doesn't my program work? I want to use the borderlayout, and each button to do different thing. I did a lot of research but I am still getting errors, and just am lost.

thank you for your help in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

  public class Guard10 {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
       new Guard10()
 }   

  public Guard10()
  {       
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setTitle("Show BorderLayout");
    myFrame.setSize(300, 200);
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Add buttons to the frame
    JButton labelButton = new JButton ("one");
    labelButton.addActionListener(new LabelListener()
    {
        @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println ("You clicked it!");
            }
    });
    ////////////
    JButton button2 = new JButton ("two");
    button2.addActionListener(new Button2Listener()
    {
         @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println ("YAY!");
            }
      }
     myFrame.add(labelButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);       
     myFrame.add(button2,BorderLayout.NORTH)
            myFrame.setVisible(true);   

   }
  }
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace so we can see the error

Comment: What kind of errors? Compilation? Exceptions? Misbehavior?

Comment: I apologize for not putting the errors. I got 11 errors: majority of it is "cannot find symbol"

Comment: Look at my answer Rid, I fixed your code half an hour ago. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You simply forgot some semicolons and brackets. The corrected code below is working. Also, use a standard `ActionListener` if you do nothing but overriding `actionPerformed`.

```
public class Guard10 {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Guard10();
  }

  public Guard10()
  {
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setTitle("Show BorderLayout");
    myFrame.setSize(300, 200);
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Add buttons to the frame
    JButton labelButton = new JButton ("one");
    labelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {
        System.out.println ("You clicked it!");
      }
    });
    ////////////
    JButton button2 = new JButton ("two");
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {
        System.out.println ("YAY!");
      }
    });
        myFrame.add(labelButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    myFrame.add(button2,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

If you try to compile you get all the errors in the stacktrace. Just look at the lines to find out what is wrong. I'd also advice you to use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea, they will mark syntax errors before compiling while you type the code.